# Anaconda Navigator won't launch a notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I have anaconda installed which comes with a base(root) environment. I have downloaded python from python.org and I have VSC. I open Anaconda Navigator and click launch on Jupyter notebook to no avail. It will only open if I search for it with the windows key. The reason this is a big problem is because I am trying to use jupyter with a different environment which I could launch from navigator but as you can see in the video, it just won't work. Please help, Thanks!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iO57l5xGpw0

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Installing standard Python on top of the Anaconda stack is asking for trouble. So what's exactly on your system path now? Anyhow, you can always install jupyter notebook into any other virtual environment and you don't need the Navigator at all. It's just a gimmic for newbees. But I guess you know that.